# import virtual machine to vsphere server use vmware workstation

Tags: import, vmware, vsphere

I use VMware workstation(v12.5)

I want to import virtual machine into vSphere server.

I also use vsphere client. It can import virtual machine(ovf, ova).

But I want to use VMware workstation.

"File > open" can import virtual machine only local.

help me~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://totori.tistory.com/176

vmware vcenter converter standalone can convert virtual machine.